# F# Optional CSV load

Tags: f#, f#-data

I'm using the F# data provider to load csv files. For some reason, not in my control, they occasionally change the file to a gzip. (e.g. MyFile.txt could also be MyFile.text.gz)

So, I have this and it works just fine

```
let fl = CSV.load("MyFile.txt")
```

What I need to be able to do is if this errors with file not found, I need it to look for the alternate name.

```
let fl = CSV.load("MyFile.txt.gz")
```

I've tried a try...with block

```
try
        let fl = CSV.load("MyFile.txt")
with
        let fl = CSV.load("MyFile.txt.gz")
```

It won't let me use let keyword in this fashion. I even tried

```
try
        let fl = CSV.load("MyFile.txt")
with
        CSV.load("MyFile.txt.gz") -> fl
```

With C#, this would be pretty straight forward. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: In which library does CSV.load exist? I've been searching and cannot find it.

Comment: You use fsharp.data.dll then set the type like
type Stocks = CsvProvider<"../data/MSFT.csv">

Comment: RT1138 Thanks for the reference to  fsharp.data.dll.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
let fl =
    try CSV.load("MyFile.txt")
    with _ -> CSV.load("MyFile.txt.gz")
```

But I believe a better solution would be to check if the file exists first.